# maven release plugin for git branch - No such provider: 'git' error

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

We have recently migrated to git from svn and while trying to create a release build we are facing some challenges. Please suggest if anyone has any solution to the below error.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-4:create
>   (generate-buildnumber) on project ebcm-jar: Cannot get the branch
>   information from the scm repository :
>
> No such provider: 'git'.

SCM details in pom ->

```
<scm>  
 <connection>scm:git:https://stash.gto.intranet.com:8081/scm/application.git</connection>  
  <developerConnection>scm:git:https://stash.gto.intranet.com:8081/scm/application.git</developerConnection>  
  <url>https://stash.gto.intranet.com:8081/scm/application</url>  
</scm>
```

Current release plugin config ->

```
<plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>2.5.3</version>  
    <dependencies>  
     <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>  
      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>  
      <version>1.9.5</version>  
     </dependency>  
    </dependencies>  
    <configuration>  
     <stagingrepository>  
      team-release::default::http://gmrepo:8678/nexus-webapp/content/repositories/ebcm-releases/  
     </stagingrepository>  
     <connectionUrl>  
      scm:git:https://stash.gto.intranet.com:8081/scm/application.git  
     </connectionUrl>  
     <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>  
     <remoteTagging>true</remoteTagging>  
     <updateBranchVersions>true</updateBranchVersions>  
     <updateWorkingCopyVersions>true</updateWorkingCopyVersions>  
     <tagBase>https://stash.gto.intranet.com:8081/scm/application.git</tagBase>  
    </configuration>  
   </plugin>
```

Have tried searching and trying multiple options from similar posts like below but nothing seems to fix it.

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/No-such-provider-git-td83846.html

[Maven SCM Plugin: Git SSH provider not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625295/maven-scm-plugin-git-ssh-provider-not-found)

So far have verified the urls,plugin versions, verified the dependencies are getting downloaded for gitexe provider, tried ssh urls instead of https

Have also encountered this article , so is Git Flow is the only option here?
https://blog.avisi.nl/2015/04/07/improved-releasing-with-maven-and-git/

Comment: Simply you are using an too old version of org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-4 plugin. Current version is 3.0.0 see http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks a ton!...so far I was only focusing on the error 'No GIT provider' but didn't check this mojo version...upgrading it to 1.4 (which is available in our org repo) solved the error.